# Встроенный редактор

Tags: wysiwyg, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте, у меня есть встроенный редактор wysiwyg, который не хочет работать в Internet Explorer (программа для стачивания браузера :) ), может ли кто-нибудь предложить альтернативу? Например, мне очень нравится редактор как на http://hashcode.ru (здесь), возможно его где-нибудь заполучить? Либо есть какие-либо другие.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да их дохрена.

- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
- [markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)

Нагуглите что-нибудь типа «wysiwyg editors for web», и будет вам счастье.

Разметка, которая используется здесь на hashcode, называется [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/). Если вам нужна именно она, то смотрите, какой из редакторов ее поддерживает. Их тоже множество, например, [ittyeditor](http://code.google.com/p/ittyeditor/).